# Why the max value for cx, cy in <radialGradient> is 1

Tags: html, svg, radial-gradients

The code from an online SVG basic course:

```
<body class="site">
    <figure class="theimage">
        <svg id="custom-shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">

            <defs>
                <radialGradient id="sky" cx=".7" cy=".4" r=".5">
                    <stop stop-color="#00dffe" offset="0%" />
                    <stop stop-color="#38a3d1" offset="100%" />
                </radialGradient>
                <radialGradient id="sun">
                    <stop stop-color="yellow" offset="80%" />
                    <stop stop-color="hsla(60, 100%, 50%, 0)" offset="100%" />
                </radialGradient>
            </defs>

            <rect fill="url(#sky)" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" />
            <circle fill="url(#sun)" cx="350" cy="200" r="100" />
        </svg>
    </figure>
</body>
```

The `cx` and `cy` value range is 0 ~ 1, why not 500, 500 (set in `viewBox`)?

In the following code:

```
<body class="site">
    <figure class="theimage">
        <svg id="custom-shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <circle class="stroke fill" cx="40" cy="60" r="20" />
        </svg>
    </figure>
</body>
```

I guess it's because `<radiaGradient>` is 'nested' in the outer circle or other outer shape, so `cx` or `cy` ranges from 0 to 1 (or 100%). But I don't find some references online. Please clarify this out for me or provide me some useful links to the references? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SVG specification may have what you are looking for:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#RadialGradientElementCXAttribute

*"The gradient will be drawn such that the 100% gradient stop is mapped to the perimeter of this largest (i.e., outermost) circle."*

Also, the spec contains this:

*"When percentages are used with attributes that define the gradient vector, the pattern tile, the filter region or the masking region, a percentage represents the same value as the corresponding decimal value (e.g., 50% means the same as 0.5)."*

(https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ObjectBoundingBoxUnits)

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of gradients is to express sizes in fractions of the bounding box of the element the gradient is applied to.

To change this behavior, you can use the attribute [`gradientUnits`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#RadialGradientElementGradientUnitsAttribute):

- `objectBoundingBox` uses fractions of the bounding box (default).
- `userSpaceOnUse` uses the same coordinate system as the element the gradient is applied to.